# Toc disappears after adding the acronym key

Tags: table-of-contents, errors, indexing, acronyms

I'm trying to write my own notes.
I had added the listing of acronyms on top of my file, but when I compile my project, for an unknown reason an error pops out of my IDE, and it says:
`Missing \endcsname inserted. <to be read again>`
The line in which it occurs is:
`\newacro{$\varepsilon $-NFA}[\AC@hyperlink{$\varepsilon $-NFA}{$\varepsilon $-NFA}]{Epsilon NFA}`
And the tex code is this:\

*document.tex* [that is an input for my main file]

```
\newpage
\vspace*{\fill}
{\centering Questa pagina è stata intenzionalmente lasciata in bianco\par}
\vspace{\fill}
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\input{tex/Legenda}
\input{tex/Lezione1}
```

*Legenda.tex*

```
Legenda:
\begin{acronym}[VBLAST]  % longest acronym to fix width
    \acro{f(tran)}{Funzione di Transizione}\acused{f(tran)}
    \acro{DFA}{Automa a Stati Finiti Deterministico}\acused{DFA}
    \acro{NFA}{Automa a Stati Finiti Non Deterministico}
    \acro{$\eps$-NFA}{Epsilon NFA}
\end{acronym}
\newpage
```

Basically in my index page at the beginning, the toc seems to disappear, even if the pdf file is "correctly" generated.
I also tried to include Legenda in the toc, but the result is the same.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter of `\acro` must be simple ASCII characters, or something that expands to that (in TeX terms, it must expand to character tokens). If you have anything else, you should choose a name that complies and put the real stuff in an optional argument, like:

```
\acro{eps-NFA}[$\varepsilon$-NFA]{Epsilon NFA}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You made my day ;D